# powershell cut off repo name

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have a strings in file:

```
git@github.com:myorg/Myrepo.git
git@github.com:myorg/Mysecondrepo.git
git@github.com:myorg/Myrepo-old.git
```

I need to cut from this strings only repo name (Myrepo, Mysecondrepo, Myrepo-old). How to do this in Powershell?

I tried:

```
foreach($link in $gitlink)
{
    $s = $link
    $s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('/'))
    echo $s
}
```

But it always returns me git@github.com:myorg. How to rewrite this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Regular Expression with a (capture group) to directly strip off everything and just keep the repo name.

```
$Repos = (Get-Content '.\gitlinks.txt') -replace '^.*/(.*)\.git$','$1'
$Repos
```

---

```
Myrepo
Mysecondrepo
Myrepo-old
```

**EDIT: incorporated into your script from scrrenshot**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51423853.ps1
Set-Location 'C:\a\'

ForEach($link in $gitlink){
    git clone $link
    $repodir = $link -replace '^.*/(.*)\.git$','$1'
    $repodir
    Push-Location $repodir
    git --no-pager --oneline --before 2018-07-1 --after 2012-06-10 | 
        Out-File -FilePath c:\a\commits.txt
    Pop-Location
}
```

Comment: Well, I need data from txt file, in my further actions. Is there any way, to transform this value in array, like here - http://prntscr.com/k8fy9w  ?

Comment: You can very well use the same RegEx on $Link in your screenshot `$repodir = $link -replace '^.*/(.*)\.git$','$1'`

Comment: BTW the `.TrimEnd()` method doesn't take `.git` as a a whole but keeps trimming every single character from the end until none of them present, thus also eliminating the `ì` from api.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
foreach($link in $gitlink)
{
    $s = $link.Split('/')[1].TrimEnd('.git')
    echo $s
}
```

Explanation:

1. `Split('/')` cuts the string into two parts
2. `[1]` chooses the part after the `/`
3. `TrimEnd('.git')` cuts the last `.git` from the string.

As an alternative you could stick to your try and do it like this:

```
foreach($link in $gitlink)
{
    $s = $link.Substring(($link.IndexOf('/')+1) , ($link.Length - $link.IndexOf('/') -5))
    echo $s
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such extensive explanation!

Comment: @VasiliyVegas I added another option if you want to stick to `Substring` and `IndexOf`.

Comment: Unfortunately, second method is not working. And in first (where $link.Split) some repos are cutting with some additional symbols. I cannot understand why - perhaps you can give me a hint, because I cannot find a sequence, why?
For example - string git@github.com:myorg/MineqConfigApi.git It cuts to MineqConfigAp - as on screenshot http://prntscr.com/k8fy9w   Majority repos are ok, but few processing wrong

Comment: @VasiliyVegas I had a typo in the second one, it should work now. I can't explain why it cuts the extra letter in the first one.

Comment: Second works like a charm now. All repos are extracted. Thanks!